# Cannot run a Specflow test in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, specflow

I am getting a strange error when running a specflow feature file test. So it won't even start the test before it fails.

**"Cannot create an instance of Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext because it is an abstract class"**

I haven't changed anything recently though it is an area I have not worked on for a while. I have multiple projects in the solution and all other projects are fine

I have tried the following

1. Closed and re-opened Visual Studio
2. Deleted the feature.cs file and regenerated feature files
3. Removed cache specflow files for the project from the TEMP folder.

Any ideas? As far as I can see my version of Specflow is the same as the other projects within the solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Turns out one of my projects within the solution was a different SpecFlow.MSTest version. Once all were the same it worked.